# How can you replace the a), b)... numbering of subfigures by 1., 2....?

Tags: subfloats, letters

I would like to replace the caption numbering in subfigures, that is by default a), b)... by 1., 2.,... which is usually used for figures. I need this because I want some figures to be arranged side by side, for which I need the subfigure function, however, all figures should have the same "rank" and therefore be counted by sequential numbers.

Thanks for your help,
Lukas.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Far more easy we can help you if you would provide small complete document, which reproduce your problem. Anyway, see if `\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\arabic{subfigure}}` will help you.

Comment: Please tell us which subfigure-related package (if any) you employ: `subcaption`, `subfig`, or something else?